# How do I disable workspaces in Enlightenment?

Tags: workspaces, enlightenment

I installed Enlightenment 19 using [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~niko2040/+archive/ubuntu/e19), the only problem is that I keep accidentally switching workspaces whenever I put my mouse to the scroll bar at the right-hand side of my Google Chrome window. I would like to disable this accidental switching of workspaces, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable edge flipping:

- open the <kbd>Settings</kbd> panel
- tab <kbd>Input</kbd>
- select Edge Bindings.

You can disable all the edge bindings there.

[More here on this](http://www.bodhilinux.com/w/key-bindings-and-edge-bindings/). From the link:

> **The Edge Bindings Settings dialog box**
>
> To open this dialog box, go to Main menu > Settings > All > Input > Edge Bindings. It is similar to the Key Bindings dialog box shown above, with the same Action Pane contents at the right, but edge bindings listed at the left. By default no edge bindings have been set, so the left pane is empty. You can set up to eight edge bindings – one for each edge and one for each corner.

Comment: Do you use Enlightenment? o_O

Comment: Nope. Question can be answered straight from a manual.